# setInterval and Ajax issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval, multiple-instances

I am running an ajax call every 10 minutes with setinterval.  That call is getting new post data from a php page and throwing it into a variable.  When I want to load that new post data, I would click on a link and it will prepend to the page.

I am running into the issue of, if the page is sitting inactive for 30 minutes, it runs the ajax call 3 times (every time minutes).  Then, when I click the link to load the new posts, they are loaded 3 times.

I need them to only be loaded once.

Here is my code.

```
    var getNewPosts = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'interactions/get_new_posts.php',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function(results) {
            var data = results;
            // New Posts
            var instagramPosts = $(data).find('#instagramPosts').html();


            //Load new Instagram Posts
            $(document).one('click', '.instagram_menu', function(e) {
                $('#feed_wrap').prepend(instagramPosts).isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
                console.log(instagramPosts);
            });

        },
        error: function(results) {
            //console.log('true', results);


        }
    });
};

var interval = 1000 * 60 * 10; // Last int is minutes
setInterval(getNewPosts, interval);
```

So you can see it loads the new posts into the variable instagramPosts.  Then when I clicked .instagram_menu, it prepends those new posts.

Again, the issue is, if I let it sit to were it calls this function multiple times, then I click .instagram_menu, it loads those posts the amount of times the function has been called.

Where do I go with this?  I'd like to be pointed in the right direction to learn, don't just give me the code and call it a day.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would unbind the click then bind again. I'm not sure what 'one' does?

```
setInterval(bang, 1000);


function bang(){

$('#clickme').unbind('click');
$('#clickme').one('click', function(){

    alert('bang');

});


}
```

Comment: Yeah I think you want to unbind the click "The first form of this method is identical to .bind(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation". Every time you call the function it binds another click event which is then unbound once clicked or invoked. Unbind works with one also http://jsfiddle.net/jY2sg/

Comment: The issue is it's prepending the data x amount of times the function has been called.  I can prevent the click from happening more than once, it's the data that is being prepended when it's clicked.

Comment: Yes but I think a click is being bound to .instagram_menu every time getNewPosts is called by setinterval. So if getNewPosts is called 3 times, 3 click events are added to .instagram_menu. So if the click event is fired all three click events run and so 3 click function run. So the unbind would remove a click event before adding another one to .instagram_menu.